# NodeJS - stat doesn't always run

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here's my code:

```
console.log("Path 1: " + fullName);
fs.stat(fullName, function(err, stats) {
 console.log("Path 2: " + fullName);
}, function(err) { // I don't know if this part actually does something
  console.log("An error occurred: " + err); // but I saw it in a different SO answer
});
```

The code simply doesn't run for some files. As in, my logs will show Path 1 with the file but not path 2 with the file, and also none of the "an error occurred". I was thinking maybe the files have an invalid character, because they all have equal signs in them. They look like this:

```
   ...file.device_type=mobile.jsx
```

Even if that's the case, why no error or anything? And if so, how can I actually stat these files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't logging or checking for an error.  `fs.stat()` accepts two parameters only, the filename and a callback function.  You are passing three parameters, the filename and two separate callbacks.  So that second callback is just wrong.  Then, in the first callback, you need to check the `err` variable to see if an error occurred.

This is the correct usage:

```
fs.stat(fullName, function(err, stats) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error in fs.stat(): ", err);
    } else {
        console.log("Got stats: ", stats);
    }
});
```

If you're using this proper form and you still don't see either message in the console, then I'd suggest putting an exception handler around it to see if something else is going on:

```
try {
    console.log("about to call fs.stat()");
    fs.stat(fullName, function(err, stats) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error in fs.stat(): ", err);
        } else {
            console.log("Got stats: ", stats);
        }
    });
 } catch(e) {
    console.log("fs.stat() exception: ", e);
 }
```

In looking at the [source code for `fs.stat()`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/fs.js#L929), there are several ways it could throw a synchronous exception, particularly if it detects invalid arguments passed to it.  As usual, the node.js documentation does not describe that behavior, but you can see it in the code.  This is the code for `fs.stat()`:

```
fs.stat = function(path, callback) {
  callback = makeStatsCallback(callback);
  if (handleError((path = getPathFromURL(path)), callback))
    return;
  if (!nullCheck(path, callback)) return;
  var req = new FSReqWrap();
  req.oncomplete = callback;
  binding.stat(pathModule._makeLong(path), req);
};
```

Both `makeStatsCallback()` and `handleError()` can throw an exception (when you look at their implementations in that same file).

---

I do not know where you got the notion of passing two callbacks to `fs.stat()`.  As documented [here](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_stat_path_callback), it does not accept two callback functions.  It looks remotely like a promisified version of the `fs` library where every async operation returns a promise and then you can pass two callbacks to `fs.statPromise.then(fn1, fn2)`, but I have no idea if that's where you saw this or not.

Comment: Added more info about how `fs.stat()` can throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_stat_path_callback
As per the documentation it shouldn't have the 3rd param function

Comment: Can you clarify? I'm not sure what you're telling me to change.

Comment: fs.stat(fullName, function(err, stats) {
 console.log("Path 2: " + fullName);
});